# What's the best way to handle invalid arguments in scala

Tags: scala

I'm writing a function that takes a request object, there are several ways that the request could be configured, but only one valid form, so before I perform my function I'd like to test how the object is configured.  If I were doing this in java, I'd write something like this:

```
static void func(Request request) {
  if (condition1)
    return false

  if (condition 2)
    return false

  if (condition 3)
    return false

  request.process()
  return true
}
```

In scala though, in trying to avoid using return, I usually end up with this:

```
static void func(Request request) {
    if (!condition1) {
        if (!condition 2) {
            if (!condition 3) {
                request.process()
                return true
            }
            else
                return false
        }
        else
            return false
    }
    else
      return false
}
```

This is a simplified form as usually there are things that I need to do after condition 1, and then after condition 2, which mean that I can't just combine the conditions into a single if statement (e.g. condition 1 checks that something isn't null, then condition 2 checks if the value of that thing is valid).

What I'm wondering is how do I make my code clean and readable whilst still having these checks in place?

Comment: what do you mean by " in trying to avoid using return"? I see there are return statements in the second example also. Also, are your conditions involve some common variable by any chance?

Comment: You may want to compose your conditions _(using something like [`Validated`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html))_. However, if you are not familiar with **FP**, and terms like Applicative or Monad, you may need to study those things first.

Answer (score 4):

you can use pattern matching

```
request match {
    case _ if (condition1 || condition2 || condition3) => false
    case _ => request.process(); true
}
```

Comment: He has stated as part of the question that he can't combine the conditions as he need to handle some specific logic per condition.

Comment: In that case , he has to add 2 more case statement. I think that is not a big deal.

Comment: I could add the extra cases, but suppose the logic to get condition2 is like 10-20 lines of code.  Is a case statement still visually the best way to represent that?   I could put the manipulation code into a function and then just call that from the case, but that will hide functionality (which could be good or bad).

Answer (score 4):

In Scala it is usual to return `Option[value]` rather than returning `true`/`false` and relying on side effects. And a `Request` object would normally be pure data, with processing done by an external function.

So a typical Scala function might look like this:

```
def func(req: Request): Option[Result] =
  req match {
    case Request(a, _, _) if condition1(a) => None
    case Request(_, b, _) if condition2(b) => None
    case _ =>
      Some(processRequest(req))
  }
```

Comment: Maybe worth exploring Either[X,Y] to return a valid result OR an error message

Comment: I would vote for `Try` rather than `Either` for error handling, but both are good options if you want to preserve the reason for failure.

Comment: The only reason I used true/false than an option was to illustrate a reponse.  The actual code I've adapted returns a monix task, as it's all async.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do a simple if else simplifying your conditions.

```
def func(request: Request) {
    if (condition1 || condition2 || condition3)
        false
    else {
        request.process()
        true
    }
}
```

Comment: As stated in the question, I can't combine the conditions together in my case.  For example suppose I need to check condition1 before I check condition2, because condition2 cannot be valid before checking that condition1 is valid.

Comment: The `||` operator will make sure that checks are done in order, and will skip later conditions if earlier conditions return `true`.